# detection of vertical texts (container BIC codes) with tesseract OCR fails

Tags: ocr, tesseract, detection, image-recognition, python-tesseract

I'm trying to use [Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract) for a text detection of intermodal (shipping) containers codes in [BIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_6346) format. BTW, I'm using tesseract through pytesseract and I preprocess input photos with few standard opencv filtering (huge rescaling/blurring/denoising/binarization).

I tuned tesseract (version: tesseract 5.0.0-alpha-647-g4a00) in this way:

```
  config = (
    # only a set of characters
    ' -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' +

    # no language model
    ' -c load_system_dawg=0' +
    ' -c load_freq_dawg=0' +

    ' -c enable_new_segsearch=1' +

    ' -c language_model_penalty_non_freq_dict_word=1' +
    ' -c language_model_penalty_non_dict_word=1' +

    # select segmentation mode
    ' --psm 11'
  )
```

I got hopeful results when codes are horizontal-aligned, as in this case:

[image]

but I have issues with vertical texts, as in the example show in the photo:

[image]

In this last case tesseract doesn't produce an useful result. Why tesseract fails event if input image seems "good"? Any suggestion about how to improve engine recognition?

Answer (score 0):

Try running with `--psm 5` :

```
pagesegmode values are:
  5 = Assume a single uniform block of vertically aligned text.
```